# Issue with passing field variable to subreport from master report

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I am trying to do a simple expression in iReport, but whatever I try seems hasn't given me which I expected. It seems like such a simple thing to do, but I couldn't understand what's happening with my code.

All I'm trying to do is show a subreport when the value of an string field is a simple word like "VALUE". I am using the Print When Expression for the subreport control, however I'm not able to the see or reproduce this text with this expression. For me seems that I'm not passing well the parameters I wan't to use to do the print when expression in the subreport from the master report.

Is a disclaimer, so in master report I have a simple subreport, with the same conection from master and one parameter called Entity = "_id.Entity" (we use mongodb to get the fields for the report with a $group) and in the subreport part I have 2 text fields, the first one have the print when expression when P{Entity}.equals("VALUE"), the second one don't have any condition so this works perfectly, but the textfield with the condition doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show your code.